# Solution does not recognize csproj as c# project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, csproj

We have large solutions that have both vb and c# projects. We're on the path of converting some of vb to c#. 
After the conversion, when solution is opened using vs2017 project is still shows as vb. We can build it but code is unusable. 
We have the fix - remove project from solution and re-add it. Voila - it shows as csproj. But this creates new issue - since we're using DLL references, we have to manually set build order. Build order is broken when project is removed.

My thinking was that solution must be caches something somewhere. I removed `.vs`, cleaned solution, removed all `obj` folders, no matter what I cleaned out, until you re-add project, a c# project shows as vb project. I also checked `c:\users\username\...` for any files that can relate to my solution and found nothing.

I hate do re-add and fix build order many times (conversions will not happen all at once). Why VS is not recognizing file right-away? After re-add, project file is not changed and solution doesn't have any sign of something different.

[image]

Comment: @HansPassant Everything is deleted. There is only cs proj on the drive and TFS. There no project references at all. Only dll references.

Comment: @HansPassant this is different discussion. My problem is why solution doesn't recognize  csproj until you re-add it

Comment: @HansPassant there are no error messages. Project builds fine. It just recognized as vb. You just have editor havoc because VS decided that this is vbproj. Re-add and fix build order - works. Why not from first time? It just burning me now.

Comment: @HansPassant well... I mentioned that I did clean action. Moreover, I deleted entire local source and reloaded it from TFS. I deleted all .suo files I found (`.vs`). I [almost] know, this is some caching. I just can't find the source.

Comment: @HansPassant I did what I've done. Then sent solution and projects to another developer. He opened up - still VB proj. So, he couldn't have any caching on his machine. I went even further to make solution file as close as possible, with only difference - GUID. This is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue

The GUID in solution file is actually project type GUID.

```
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}") = "projectname", "projectname.vbproj", "{7CC2FC9A-0D8F-4A26-A891-80B1D20C773D}"
EndProject
```

Above, `Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}")` is **project type** GUID;
and `"{7CC2FC9A-0D8F-4A26-A891-80B1D20C773D}"` is project ID GUID.

So, when in solution we change extension `vbproj` to `csproj`, we also need to change GUID with correct one. This solves the issue.